# geom_contour breaks (greater than a value instead of a fixed value)

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour

I am trying to plot contour lines greater than a value. In the example below, if I use geom_contour() I get all the contours, if I use breaks = 0.00384 then I get just for that break, is there a way to say all breaks greater than 0.00384? I tried breaks >  0.00384 but I get an error Error in `geom_contour()`:
! `mapping` must be created by `aes()`
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

```
library(ggplot2)

(v <- ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions, z = density)))
v + geom_contour()
v + geom_contour(breaks=0.00384)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `breaks=` argument of `geom/stat_contour` can be a numeric vector of breaks or a function which takes the range of the data and the bin width as arguments and returns a vector of breaks, e.g. by default the breaks are computed as `pretty(z_range, 10)`.

Hence, you could pass any function to the `breaks=` argument, e.g. the code below uses a function which gives 4 breaks > 0.000384 using `seq()` and dropping the first aka the break 0.000384:

Note: When passing a function to the `breaks=` argument it's important to set `binwidth=` or `bins=` to a non `NULL` value, which looks like a bug to me.

```r
library(ggplot2)

v <- ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions, z = density))

v +
  geom_contour(
    color = "red"
  ) +
  geom_contour(
    binwidth = 1, 
    breaks = \(z_range, binwidth) {
      seq(.000384, z_range[2], length.out = 5)[-1]
    }
  )
```

[image]